# DriverToaster.exe is reporting that "The parameter is incorrect."

Tags: windows-10, malware

Just today I received a slightly unsettling and almost malware-esque warning:

[image]

Apparently DriverToaster.exe is reporting that `The parameter is incorrect.`

What is this program and is it a problem?

Comment: Same situation here.. I think their servers are down

Comment: For those that are interested I have managed to raise a support ticket with Dell to try and get an explanation, but I don't hold out much hope.

Comment: I got this message on 12 August 2017 at around 1830 EST. I am wondering if there's been any update you could share from your end @Mokubai?

Comment: @J.Ari  Only that Dell has (rather vaguely) confirmed that it is most likely one of their applications as I described below. The best I got from them was an update to the SupportAssist application. There has been no explanation for the cause of the error itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would appear that this is one of the parts of the Dell SupportAssist tool.  The `AppxManifest.xml` in the directory:

> DisplayName="Dell SupportAssist" Description="SupportAssist Driver Update"

It appears that this is a legitimate program preinstalled by Dell, and not a drive-by malware download.  It could be simply a bug or inability to contact a Dell server.

The full `AppxManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities">
  <Identity Name="DriverToaster" ProcessorArchitecture="x86" Publisher='CN="PC-Doctor, Inc.", O="PC-Doctor, Inc.", L=Reno, S=Nevada, C=US' Version="1.3.0.0" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>SupportAssist Driver Update</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Dell Inc.</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\SupportAssist.150x150.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="en-us" />
  </Resources>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14257.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.15063.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
  </Capabilities>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="DriverToaster" Executable="DriverToaster.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="Dell SupportAssist" Description="SupportAssist Driver Update" BackgroundColor="#777777"
      Square150x150Logo="Assets\SupportAssist.150x150.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\SupportAssist.44x44.png"/>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
</Package>
```

I'll update this with more info if I find it.  For now it is enough to know it is not malware.

---

Checking in the Apps & Features control panel I had two "Dell SupportAssist" programs.  One was ~580KB, the other 48.1MB. It looked like the 580KB one was a UWP app as I was given the option to "Move" it. Uninstalling this one appears to have removed the folder `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\DriverToaster_1.3.0.0_x86_rqs2nt378nwsp\`